# Flutter how to print data with zebra thermal printer using bluetooth

Tags: ios, flutter, printing, bluetooth

I'm facing a serious problem to print receipt using Bluetooth for sending to thermal printer Zebra. I successfully connected to printer's Bluetooth, but nothing happen when I want to print. I used an Ipad to test.

```
Future<void> printWithDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {        
const PaperSize paper = PaperSize.mm80;     
final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();        
print(device.state.length);      
final gen = Generator(PaperSize.mm58, await CapabilityProfile.load());     
final printer = BluePrint(chunkLen: 512);      
printer.add(gen.qrcode('https://altospos.com'));     
printer.add(gen.text('Hello'));     
printer.add(gen.text('World', styles: const PosStyles(bold: true)));     
printer.add(gen.feed(1));     
await printer.printData(device);     
//device.disconnect();
```

}

Please I need help, I spent 5 days to find a solution. Excuse me for my english!

Comment: Ensure that the printer supports ESC/POS (and/or in ESC/POS mode).

Answer (score 0):

I using bixolon printer for android device.
For printing use the native bixolon sdk for android and get connection  by platform channel.
For handelling bluetooth connection , using an flutter bluetooth package on pub.dev . For solve problem like me , need native sdk of your printer .

Comment: Hi, I use Flutter_blue for looking Bluetooth devices available. And I successfully connected to printer. I'll look for native sdk of my printer (Zebra ZQ620) and try again. The most problem, I think it's to send data from my app to the printer.

Comment: connect to printer is step one . send data to printer , is next step. for this need native sdk.